# Fedora / GitLab SSH Denied, Help Understanding Verbose Logs

Tags: logging, ssh, permissions, gitlab, fedora

My ssh connection to gitlab fails on my fedora 28 box, with no password request needed. This is preventing me from successfully running needed git commands. I've researched this thoroughly within SO and Googs, but nothing I found seems to work for my issue, more importantly, help explain the various sections of a 'vvv' log.

## Set Up

> *Selinux = disabled*
>
> SSH directory: /home/justin/.ssh
>
> ```
>     drwx------   2 justin   root  4096 Nov 19 22:16  .ssh
> ```
>
> ***Step 1)*** Create the keys: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "j.r.schwimmer@domain.com"`
>
> I accept the default location and then enter a pass phrase creating:
>
> ```
>     -rw------- 1 justin root 3326 Nov 19 22:16 id_rsa
>
>     -rw-r--r-- 1 justin root  749 Nov 19 22:16 id_rsa.pub
> ```
>
> ***Step 2)*** Grab the contents of id_rsa.pub and add the key to Gitlabs SSH section, verifying that the *entire* public key is entered into Gitlabs form.
>
> ***Step 3)*** Verify that the ssh-agent is running: `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
>
> ***Step 4)*** Add the private key: `ssh-add /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa`
>
> ***Step 5)*** Run my ssh command: `ssh -vvvT justin@gitlab.domainname.net`
>   Confirming that the connection should create a known hosts file
>
> ***Step 6)*** Cry after seeing: `justin@gitlab.domainname.net: Permission denied (publickey)`

## The Verbose (vvv) Log

Loads config settings including those found in gitlab.conf:

```
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0h-fips  27 Mar 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 2: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 8: Applying options for *
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/gitlab.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/gitlab.conf
```

Makes connection:

```
debug2: resolving "gitlab.domainname.net" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.domainname.net [17.17.17.17] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

Identity File Section...**(Not sure what its doing?)**

```
debug1: identity file /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/justin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
            ...checking others
debug1: identity file /home/justin/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
```

More logs that appear to be handshake related **(I think?)** / known_hosts setup:

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.domainname.net:22 as 'justin'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.domainname.net
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
```

Known host check:

```
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:hyO5F3tsdf34PQGAYYhmoGW5J/leBnC0hj3IoE1F68
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.domainname.net
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 17.17.17.17
debug1: Host 'gitlab.domainname.net' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
```

Final Auth Verfication:

```
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55d580f2caf0), agent
debug2: key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_xmss ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:xbGUrKDgYhF34QYM1s20flfoVcjegZpbMwDDbpTmF1c /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

**(A)** Is the auth section below responsible for the overall failure? 
**(B)** It seems to be trying to load every key type after successfully trying id_rsa, is that correct?

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/justin/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/justin/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/justin/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/justin/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
justin@gitlab.domainname.net: Permission denied (publickey).
```

## Failed Tests

- I've tried setting this all up as a root user... failed
- Changing key files ownership, groups and permissions... failed
- I've tried different key types (id_ecdsa)... failed
- I tried adding a config file to /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/ that contained the following:

  ```
  Host gitlab.com
     StrictHostKeyChecking no
     LogLevel VERBOSE
  ```

## More Questions

**(C)** `debug1: identity file /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0`: Line within the "Identity File Section", is this 0 value supposed to be 2? What does this value even mean, the number of key files it found per type?

**(D)** I'm unable to find an auth.log (or any logging for ssh) file within: `/var/log/`, why would that be or how can I fix this (Fedora 28)?

Thanks you for your time!

## UPDATED: The Verbose (vvvv) Log

```
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0h-fips  27 Mar 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 2: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 8: Applying options for *
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/gitlab.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/gitlab.conf
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/gitlab.conf line 2: Applying options for gitlab.domainname.net
debug2: resolving "gitlab.domainname.net" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0                                                                                                
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.domainname.net [17.17.17.17] port 22.                                                                     
debug1: Connection established.                                                                                                       
debug1: identity file /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0                                                                                 
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory                                                                                    
debug1: identity file /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1                                                                           
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7                                                                                      
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1                                          
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000                                                         
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK                                                                                                       
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.domainname.net:22 as 'justin'                                                                           
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts"                                                                
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts:1                                                  
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.domainname.net                                                                          
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521                                       
debug3: send packet: type 20                                                                                                          
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent                                                                                                         
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:hyO5F3t2OPc2nPQGAYYhmoGW5J/leBnC0hj3IoE1F68
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.domainname.net
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 17.17.17.17
debug1: Host 'gitlab.domainname.net' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55568d375a80), agent
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:xbGUrKDgYhF34QYM1s20flfoVcjegZpbMwDDbpTmF1c /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
justin@gitlab.domainname.net: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: You ssh folder and key permission are correct and good. Nothing wrong about that. have you add ssh keys to https://gitlab.com/profile/keys ? if you self hosted gitlab, find it on setting menu

Comment: post full `ssh -vvvv git@gitlab.com` log. This will helping to identify the problem.

Comment: Hello @RobbiNespu, thanks for checking out the permissions. I have added the public key to gitlab's site. (it isn't self hosted.) Also thanks for the "-vvvv" tip! I'll review that and post it if your answer below doesn't fix my issues

Comment: Just to make sure, can you run `restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh` and test ssh?

Comment: Running that command produced no results - no files are listed as being changed, it just gave me a command prompt below. Does it matter that my SELinux is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

your [ssh folder and ssh key look good](https://robbinespu.github.io/eng/2017/08/12/Resync_ssh_keys.html), just run `ssh-add -l` to see your identity, it nothing then run `ssh-add` it will configure keys itself since it installed on default `.ssh` directory and identify your identity

Use `git` username to ssh instead of your username on Gitlab instance. Change your config file into this

```
    User git
       Host gitlab.com gitlab.domainname.net
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
       TCPKeepAlive yes
       IdentitiesOnly yes
       LogLevel VERBOSE
```

add your ssh key to https://gitlab.com/profile/keys and if you are self hosted find it on setting profile menu.

try to run `ssh -vvvv git@gitlab.com` to see if it picks up the SSH key. (Do not use `sudo`)

That is proper step as show above. Below is your QA

A: You RSA key is are not succesfully read

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:xbGUrKDgYhF34QYM1s20flfoVcjegZpbMwDDbpTmF1c /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

As I can see ssh client is not able to find separate public key
    debug1: identity file /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

B: but the RSA key does't work (last line). so it try to load other keys type but not are not exist, anyway we just need one working key.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/justin/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/justin/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/justin/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/justin/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/justin/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Re-check your SELINUX status. Grep "denied" keyword from audit log. It no need to disable / change SELINUX, if blocked try to fix with `restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh`

Comment: Thanks again for your response! Let's see: ssh-add -l shows that my key has been loaded. Using either my gitlab or git accounts doesn't change the result

Changing my git config file to the recommended one produced a "garbage at end of line" error until I modified "Hostname" to "Host"

Comment: Your answer to the questions make sense, (A) the line in question just threw me off because it changed from '-1' to zero. 

I've modified my OG question to include the "-vvvv" log. The main thing I'm confused about from this log is that toward the end it appears like my public key was loaded: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:xbGUrKDgYhF34QYM1s20flfoVcjegZpbMwDDbpTmF1c /home/justin/.ssh/id_rsa